# Call a 3rd party API using 64bit jre from inside a desktop application running on 32bit jre? Is it possible?

Tags: java, dll, module, 32bit-64bit

Basically we have a very large java application that needs to be ran on 32 bit jre based on many 3rd party components that require 32 bit jre (so that they can load their own 32bit dlls).

Now, we have a new 3rd party software whos API we must call in a 64 bit jre (for the similar reason that their dlls are 64 bit only).

Is it possible for the whole application to run under 32 bit jre, and then when we need to call our new API, launch some sort of module that runs on 64 bit jre, so that the 3rd party API won't blow up when it uses it's 64 bit dlls?

FYI the development environment we use is IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possibility is to run the 3rd party software in a separate 64-bit JVM and to use [RMI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/) or a different RPC mechanism to communicate between your main JVM and the JVM running the third-party software.

Comment: This new API is a new version of an existing API we use (it is currently 32 bit, and will be 64 bit soon). So will we need to replace every API call with the new communication mechanism (socket or RMI interface)? It would be unfortunate to have to do that. Is there no way to separate all of the code in our project that calls the API into some new 64-bit module? (I imagine this is a no...because the module could not be a black box, as it makes many calls back to the 32 bit project code).